# Would questions on where to find gaming supplies on-topic?

Tags: discussion

So, say some dashing rogue with an angry black star in a purple circle for an avatar visits the site and asks a question along the lines of:

"Hey, where can I get cheap, quality [iso graph paper/regular graph paper/d4/d8/d10/d20/d100/d7/fudge dice/human slaves/dry ice (for atmosphere)/whatever else]?"

On one hand, [props](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/props) and [atmosphere](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere) questions are on-topic, and some of these may fall under that umbrella (i.e. the dry ice thing). On the other hand, finding art, [game-recommendations](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendations), and snacks have all been said to be off-topic, not to mention this kind of question could very easily draw solicitation, which isn't really something you want outside of SO. When that dashing rogue (who absolutely doesn't live in his mother's basement) had this question before, he played it safe and ventured into chat (his biceps gleaming in the moonlight, completely unobscured by cheeto-induced and -dusted flab).

So, again, would asking for places to find quality supplies be on-topic?

Comment: related: [How can I find dice...?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/31083/23970)

Comment: @nitsua60 Aaaaand that pretty much answers my question ("teach a man to fish"; and I don't think many people need to be told to look in office supply stores for bog-standard graph paper).

Comment: @BESW Not quite, it was about _supplies_ and if they're generally on topic, not _game-recs and/or how to get around off-topic closures_.

Comment: game-recs was a subset of shopping questions that were on-topic for a limited time.  Now they are off topic, along with all shopping questions of all types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  It's a shopping question and therefore off topic for all the reasons shopping questions are off topic here and across the network; I'm not going to reiterate all those reasons as they are readily discoverable.  Those questions are not a good fit for the site.

Comment: Alright, there we go.